# Application struck

Tags: android, logcat

My application is not going forward after starting and logcat shows message that I am unable to understand.

```
04-28 15:49:44.662: I/System.out(3220): Sending WAIT chunk
04-28 15:49:44.772: I/dalvikvm(3220): Debugger is active
04-28 15:49:44.932: I/System.out(3220): Debugger has connected
04-28 15:49:44.984: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:45.184: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:45.393: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:45.603: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:45.802: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:46.003: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:46.215: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:46.412: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:46.623: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:46.833: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:47.043: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:47.243: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:47.463: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:47.673: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:47.874: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:48.073: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:48.274: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:48.483: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:48.693: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:48.903: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:49.103: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:49.313: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:49.533: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:49.763: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:49.963: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:50.164: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:50.363: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:50.604: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:50.863: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:51.122: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:51.335: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:51.583: I/System.out(3220): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-28 15:49:51.843: I/System.out(3220): debugger has settled (1405)
04-28 15:50:07.182: I/System.out(3220): Database is opened
04-28 15:50:10.002: I/Choreographer(3220): Skipped 124 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-28 15:50:10.625: D/gralloc_goldfish(3220): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-28 15:50:11.652: I/Choreographer(3220): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Kindly can anyone help me solve this

Thanks in advance
Siva

Comment: Restart you device. It seems that you tried to debug your application. It happened for me when I debugged and then after a while want to run the application, it still showed the debugger mode. But I always solved my problem by restarting the phone.

Comment: Restarting means restarting the emulator? If yes I have done that still when I run it is getting struck at the same point. Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and then this problem happened?

Comment: Problem solved just restarted the emulator and system that solved.. thanks for your help

Comment: Probably it has also to do with a line like `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` in an async task you used and you didn't started the app with the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

As MUmla mentioned, Try to remove "android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()", and this worked for me. Hope it helps.